# Why Pinyin's "声母" and "韵母" were translated as "initials" and "finals"?

Tags: translation, pinyin, phonology, linguistics

Why Pinyin's "声母" and "韵母" were translated as "Initials" and "Finals", but not as "sound-mother" and "rime-mother"? What is the meaning of "Initials" and "Finals" in Linguistics or Phonology?

Comment: Kinda answered this in the other question before I saw the edits.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know any concepts similar to "Initials" and "Finals" in Linguistics or Phonology of other languages?

Comment: @PdotWang Yes. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllable describes multiple ways of analyzing syllables. The grouping is slightly different, but "onset" and "rime" are used in describing the phonology of languages all the time.